# How to code in selenium-webdriver when entering a value and then entering that value in another screen without making it hard-coded?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to code in selenium-webdriver when entering a value and then entering that value in another screen without making it hard-coded?

first screen: ID is "workorder", entered value = "WO1234"
In second screen, ID is "orderno" and I need to enter the "WO1234" without making it hard-coded so that if I enter "WO4321" the code will also enter the same. TIA

Answer (score 0):

```
    WebDriver driver;
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    String a=driver.findElement(By.id("")).getText();//Fetch id of first screen
    driver.navigate().to("The second screen");
    driver.findElement(By.id("")).sendKeys(a);//fetch id of second screen and put the value of the first screen
```

Hence,whenever the value of first screen get changes it will enter to the second screen whithout hardcoded